# php/mysql: facebook style newsfeed architecture

Tags: php, mysql, feed

want to create a facebook type newsfeed that basically lists out different events by their timestamp.  These events reside in different tables.  I have some code that lets me order a result set by timestamp from the different tables.  My problem is I don't know the right way to combine the results from queries of different tables into one result set.  I have a feeling that UNION might be the way to do it, however, UNION seems to require that the result sets have similar numbers of columns, datatypes etc. that seems a bit hard to enforce.

Some posts have suggested the right way to do this would be to crate a separate newsfeed table but that sounds cumbersome.

This is what I have so far.  Newsfeed draws different events such as comments, photo posted etc.
table comments

```
id|comment|timestamp
```

photos

```
id|name|timestamp

$sql = "SELECT p.name,p.timestamp from  `photos` p
JOIN
SELECT c.commentc.timestamp from `comments` c 
ORDER GREATEST(IFNULL(p.timestamp,0), IFNULL(c.timestamp,0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` and just use `null` in the position of non-matching columns

```
SELECT id, comment, null as name, timestamp FROM comments
UNION
SELECT id, null as comment, name, timestamp FROM photos;
```

SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9f40f/1

Comment: Huh. Thats quite brilliant. Never realised that could be done. Generally I'd use some variant of an Outer join against another table. So perhaps a CONTENT table with a record for each type of content, and then have it outer joined to comments and photos with a content_id pointing back to it. 

One concern with your approach though is the potential for a key clash between photos.id and comments.id